# How can i render the table from the rest api

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, spring-boot, frontend

```json
{
  "firma": {
    "serialNo": 12345,
    "companyName": "facebook",
    "email": "admin@admin",
    "bankNo": 987,
    "adress": "london",
    "faturas": [
      {
        "fid": 123,
        "updateDate": [2021, 12, 14],
        "sellDate": 1241231,
        "price": 1500
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the json that I get from my API. And I am trying to make a frontend for the given API using React:

```js
class UserComponents extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    UserService.getFatura().then((response) => {
      this.setState({ users: response.data });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className="text-center">Faturalar</h2>
        <div className="row">
          <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thread>
              <tr>
                <th>User serialNo</th>
                <th>User companyName</th>
                <th>User email</th>
                <th>User bankNo</th>
                <th>User adress</th>
              </tr>
            </thread>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.users.map((users) => (
                <tr key={users.serialNo}>
                  <td> {users.serialNo}</td>
                  <td> {users.companyName}</td>
                  <td> {users.email}</td>
                  <td> {users.bankNo}</td>
                  <td> {users.adress}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default UserComponents;
```

The problem is I cant get the faturas in my json to my table in react. I try some code but didnt work i am very new and need help in react. Please make it simple as you can.
note: firma and faturas have one to many relationship serialNo is the foreign key in faturas.

Comment: In what way does this fail?  Are there any errors in the browser's development console?  In the browser's debugging tools, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  If you do `console.log(response);` in your `.then()` callback, what gets logged to the console?

Comment: are you able to currently get 'users.serialNo' etc? is it only 'users.faturas' you are having trouble getting?

Comment: @David no this doesnt fail it runs but  when i try to add the "faturas" it fails right now it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/iqqSLTJ

Comment: @AzC yes ican get the all things in users but i cant get the faturas table right now it looks like this https://imgur.com/a/iqqSLTJ but what i want is show all the faturas have but i cant add those

Comment: @MEF: That screen shot doesn't match the code shown.  If you're asking about the code which produces that screen shot, include it in the question.  Aside from that, how does it fail when you "add the faturas"?  Have you tried any debugging at all?  If you're not familiar with how to use your browser's debugging tools, that would be your first step.

Comment: @David when i tried to add faturas i write <td> {users.faturas}</td> like the others attributes but when i write it https://imgur.com/a/t64zM6b this error message appears

Comment: @MEF: In order to get a meaningful answer, it would be helpful to include the the error and the code producing the error in the question above.  As for the error itself, have you searched that exact error message on Google?  Given that `faturas` is an array of objects and not a simple value property, what output do you expect from that and why?  What would you expect that one table cell to contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data have sub-field `firma`. If you want print data first you must get this field.

Like this;

```js
{this.state.users.map(({firma}) => ( // javascript can get property like this
  <tr key={firma.serialNo}>
  <td> {firma.serialNo}</td>
  <td> {firma.companyName}</td>
  <td> {firma.email}</td>
  <td> {firma.bankNo}</td>
  <td> {firma.adress}</td>
 </tr>
))}
```

or this;

```js
{this.state.users.map((user) => (
  <tr key={user.firma.serialNo}>
  <td> {user.firma.serialNo}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.companyName}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.email}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.bankNo}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.adress}</td>
 </tr>
))}
```

If you want printing faturas, you can use this;

```js
{this.state.users.map((user) => (
  <tr key={user.firma.serialNo}>
  <td> {user.firma.serialNo}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.companyName}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.email}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.bankNo}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.adress}</td>
  <td> {user.firma.faturas.map((fatura) => (<div>
       <p>Fatura ID : {fatura.fid}</p>
       <p>Sell Date: {fatura.sellDate}</p>
       <p>Price: {fatura.price}</p>
     </div>)
  )}</td>
 </tr>
))}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iqqSLTJ i can get the firma data as showed in the picture but i cant display the "faturas" in the "firma"  {
        "fid": 123,
        "updateDate": [2021, 12, 14],
        "sellDate": 1241231,
        "price": 1500
      } i cant display this part in my json

Comment: `faturas` property is an array. You must iterate it

Comment: I edited my answer. You can see how to access to `faturas`